# Python `open` function memory usage

Tags: python, file, ram

Does Python interpreter load all the file to RAM when it is opened for writing?

```
with open('file.txt' 'w') as file:
    file.write(some_content)
```

Comment: Opening in `w` mode truncates the file anyway, so there are no contents to load into memory. Also noteworthy: `open` takes a third, optional argument, which lets you control buffer size when reading.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), open() wraps a system call and returns a file object, the file contents are not loaded into RAM (unless you invoke, E.G., readlines()).